# How can I run the following with a .bat file

Tags: windows, dos

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation"); 

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\windows\System32\sspipes.scr");
```

edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two lines seem to do what you want,

```
c:\windows\System32\ribbons.scr /s
rundll32.exe user32.dll LockWorkStation
```

Comment: note, locking the workstation seems to kill the screensaver, so to spawn the .scr first, then lock seems the way to go.

Comment: it seems that calling the screen saver example: sspipes.scr brings out it's settings and not the screen saver. do you know how I can run the screensaver not the settings?

Comment: even without /s it runs the screensavers settings instead. try it: c:\windows\System32\sspipes.scr  rundll32.exe user32.dll LockWorkStation

Comment: err, I meant the other way around. /s to *run* a screensaver executable. Works fine with sspipes.scr.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairy simple, use the following batch file:

```
@Echo off
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
%windic%\System32\ribbons.scr
```

Comment: it seems that calling the screen saver  example: sspipes.scr brings out it's settings and not the screen saver. do you know how I can run the screensaver not the settings?